# Batch rename/merge many directories

Tags: linux, bash

This is probably pretty easy, but what is the best way to rename all directories named "A" to "B" recursively below a base directory without following symbolic links and merging the contents of conflicting directories together? That is, if a "B" directory already exists, then the contents of "A" should be moved to "B", and the empty "A" directory deleted.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer that I can confirm works since I'm on Windows but something like this may be a good starting point for you if nothing else... `find "/C/Users/User/Desktop/a" -depth -type d -name "\a" -execdir mv -T -f "{}" "./b"  \;` You can likely put the RENAME command in place of the MV command or something. I couldn't get it to traverse all folders down as if it didn't have permissions to rename some but that's as close as I could get it before I ran out of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single program which performs the rename/merge function, although `mv ... -t ...` would be helpful if it could be more easily used in a `find` command. So what I have devised is:

```
find BaseDir/ -type d -name "A" | sort -r | while read d; \
     do [ -d "${d%A}B" ] && mv "$d"/* "${d%A}B"/ && rmdir "$d" || \
         mv "$d" "${d%A}B"; done
```

What this does is:-

- Find all directories with name `A`.
- Reverse sort so that, for example, `BaseDir/A/A` will be renamed before `BaseDir/A`: if the latter were renamed first, the former would not be found subsequently.
- Step through each found directory: if `B` doesn't exist, a simple rename works; otherwise, the *contents* of `A` are moved to `B` and the now empty `A` can be removed.

Note that if `B` pre-exists, any files it contains will be overwritten by files with the same name in `A`: you may want to add extra commands to prevent this - you could use `mv -i`, but you will need to re-establish the terminal for any prompting (eg `mv </dev/stdin -i ...`, or whatever your Linux supports), since `stdin` has been redirected in the script.

I have used quotes to allow for blanks in any of the path elements, including `A` and `B`.

I have tried to test different hierarchies, but I can't be sure that I have covered all the structures you might use. I suggest you put `echo` before the `mv` and `rmdir` commands first, until you have verified that the command does what you want.